# How can I get geom_smooth to plot a hyperbola as a fitting curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two variables known to be in a hyperbolic relationship using `ggplot2`. I want to add a fitting curve using `geom_smooth`.

```
geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "gam", formula = y ~ 1/x)
```

just gives me a straight line. Is it possible to force `geom_smooth` to plot a hyperbola?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
n <- 100
x <- seq(n)
y <- rnorm(n, 50 + 30 * x^(-0.2), 1)
Data <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(data = Data, 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "gam", formula = y ~ 1/x)
```

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: your formula needs a tweak: `y ~ I(1/x)`

Comment: Or if you know the exponent of `x` in the  underlying data, `y ~ I(x^0.2))`

Comment: Would someone (possibly the OP) please post one or more of these as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am posting this comment from @bouncyball to accept it as the correct answer:*

Your formula needs a tweak: y ~ I(1/x)

```
n <- 100
x <- seq(n)
y <- rnorm(n, 50 + 30 * x^(-0.2), 1)
Data <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(data = Data, 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "gam", formula = y ~ I(1/x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can use the method function here because that's used for regression and not ideal for mathematical curves like the one you referred to do. Best practice is to create a tibble with the plot and then add using `geom_smooth()` or `geom_line()` as shown below using the popular `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

graph_hyperbole <- tibble(x = 0:10) %>%
                     mutate(y = 1/x)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
         geom_point() +
         geom_smooth(data = graph_hyperbole, aes(x = x, y = y))
```